# Tensorflow string_input_producer stuck in queue

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

By following the mnist example, I was able to build a custom network and use the `inputs` function of the example to load my dataset (previously encoded as a `TFRecord`). Just to recap it, the `inputs` function looks like:

```
def inputs(train_dir, train, batch_size, num_epochs, one_hot_labels=False):

    if not num_epochs: num_epochs = None
    filename = os.path.join(train_dir,
                        TRAIN_FILE if train else VALIDATION_FILE)

    with tf.name_scope('input'):
        filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
            [filename], num_epochs=num_epochs)

        # Even when reading in multiple threads, share the filename
        # queue.
        image, label = read_and_decode(filename_queue)

        # Shuffle the examples and collect them into batch_size batches.
        # (Internally uses a RandomShuffleQueue.)
        # We run this in two threads to avoid being a bottleneck.
        images, sparse_labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
            [image, label], batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=2,
            capacity=1000 + 3 * batch_size,
            # Ensures a minimum amount of shuffling of examples.
            min_after_dequeue=1000)

    return images, sparse_labels
```

Then, during the training I declare the training operator and run everything, and everything goes smoothly.

Now, I am trying to use the very same function to train a different network on the same data, the only (major) difference is that instead of just calling the `slim.learning.train` function on some `train_operator`, I do the training manually (by manually evaluating the losses and updating the parameters). The architecture is more complex and I'm forced to do so.

When I try to use the data generated by the `inputs` function, the program gets stuck, setting a queue timeout indeed shows that it's stuck on the producer's queue. 
This leads me to believe that I'm probably missing something about the use of producers in tensorflow, I have read the tutorials but I couldn't figure out the issue. Is there some kind of initialization that calling `slim.learning.train` does and that I need to replicate by hand if I do my training manually? Why exactly isn't the producer *producing*?

For example, doing something like:

```
imgs, labels = inputs(...)
print imgs
```

prints

```
<tf.Tensor 'input/shuffle_batch:0' shape=(1, 128, 384, 6) dtype=float32>
```

which is the correct (symbolic?) tensor but if I then try to get the actual data with a `imgs.eval()` it's stuck indefinitely.

Comment: Did you try running it within a `tf.Session()`?

Comment: Yes, without the session it simply tells you that you need a session to run the `eval()`, the problem is something related to the queue not being populated or something..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start the queue runners, or the queues will be empty and reading from them will hang. See [the documentation on queue runners](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/train.html#start_queue_runners).